# Setting transparent background in PHP or CSS for WordPress (for some of the web-page elements)

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I want to make the background for my posts transparent. I dont want it to be whit out a background but just as much transparent so as you can veigly see the background. 
If its no trouble could someone make me a PHP or CSS code and instruct wher about should i put it. 
Thx in advance !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a coding service.

Comment: We are not here to do your job for you, nor teach you how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is a server side scripting language. You're not going to, or ever will make your post transparent with PHP. If you want to add opacity to your post you will be accomplishing this using css.

Find a class or ID the post is using and target it with css.

```
#posts{/*id*/
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.posts{/#class*/
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

You can also get fancy using selectors

```
.post:nth-child(2){...}
```

But you will never use PHP for your styling of html even if you really wanted to you can't.

in css you would want to use `background: rgba();` as it will only set the alpha channel for that element and text and other elements inside of it will not be effected. This will make your text readable. RGBA stands for (Red, Green, Blue, Alpha) you pass it 4 numbers from 0 to 255 for RGB and a floating number from 0.0 to 1.0 for alpha.

You will not want to use the `opacity: 0.5;` css attribute due to the fact that all child elements will inherit this attribute making your text impossible to read.

Comment: ...and 1. Google 'wordpress child themes', Google 'wordpress style.css' and 3. Google 'css opacity' to find out more :)